# key :user_id not found in. Elixir Preload problems

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to add a user_id while building a league struct but it's giving me this error:

```
** (KeyError) key :user_id not found in: %{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "leagues">, __struct__: Statcasters.Schema.League, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, name: nil, teams: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :teams is not loaded>, updated_at: nil, users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>, users_id: nil}
(stdlib) :maps.update(:user_id, {{:., [line: 14], [{:user, [line: 14], nil}, :id]}, [line: 14], []}, %{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "leagues">, __struct__: Statcasters.Schema.League, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, name: nil, teams: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :teams is not loaded>, updated_at: nil, users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>, users_id: nil})
```

Here is my controller:

#### LEAGUE CONTROLLER

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    user = Repo.get!(User, conn.assigns.current_user.id)
    changeset = %League{user_id: user.id}
      |> League.changeset()

    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
```

#### MODELS

league.ex

```
  schema "leagues" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :teams, Statcasters.Teams.Team
    belongs_to :users, Statcasters.Coherence.User

    timestamps()
  end
```

user.ex

```
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    coherence_schema()
    has_many :leagues, Statcasters.Schema.League

    timestamps()
  end
```

Do I need to use `Repo.preload`? I'm not sure what it's telling me to do?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `belongs_to :user`?

Comment: Yep! Aghh! thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the error closely, it says *`:user_id`* not found. Indeed it doesn't exist in the map that's printed, but `:users_id` does exist. This can only mean that you have a relation named `users` and not `user`, which is exactly the problem. `belongs_to :users` should be `belongs_to :user`.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow this link, https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3 , 
you will see it is mentioned under Ecto.Schema => Functions => belongs_to/3 => Options

`belongs_to(name, queryable, opts \\ [])`

> :foreign_key - Sets the foreign key field name, defaults to the name of the association suffixed by _id. For example, belongs_to :company will define foreign key of :company_id

In your case, `belongs_to :user` will define foreign key of `:user_id`